# XML Scripting for ivr

Tags: xml, ivr

**I want to play ivr through xml scripting. I've edited a running script but now it is not playing when I dialed ivr extn (820) number. Whenwver I've dialing 820 call just disconnected after 2 sec and anything didn't plays as ivr. I am using OpenUC as IPPBX and want to create an ivr for users in it. Anyone please tell me what is wrong in this script?**

```
<include>
    <menu name="test_ivr"
      greet-long="/var/sipxdata/mediaserver/data/ivrscript/CoralIVR/prompts/main.wav"
      greet-short="/var/sipxdata/mediaserver/data/ivrscript/CoralIVR/prompts/main.wav"
      invalid-sound="/var/sipxdata/mediaserver/data/ivrscript/CoralIVR/prompts/main.wav"
      exit-sound="/var/sipxdata/mediaserver/data/ivrscript/CoralIVR/prompts/main.wav"
      confirm-macro=""
      confirm-key=""
      tts-engine="flite"
      tts-voice="rms"
      confirm-attempts="3"
      timeout="10000"
      inter-digit-timeout="2000"
      max-failures="3"
      max-timeouts="3"
      digit-len="4">
    <entry action="menu-exec-app" digits="1" param="execute_extension limit:'hash ivr              in',set:acc_code=cucu,playback:/var/sipxdata/mediaserver/data/ivrscript/CoralIVR/prompts/one .wav,system:/home/george/alex/test.sh,bridge:sofia/$${domain}/101@192.168.1.240,hangup  inline"/>

     <condition field="destination_number" expression="^1234$" require-nested="true">

     <condition field="destination_number" expression="1">

 <entry action="menu-exec-app" param="execute_extension limit:'hash ivr         in',set:acc_code=cucu,playback:/var/sipxdata/mediaserver/data/ivrscript/CoralIVR/prompts/four.wav,system:/home/george/alex/test.sh,bridge:sofia/$${domain}/101@192.168.1.240,hangup inline"/>

 </condition>

 <condition field="destination_number" expression="2">

 <entry action="menu-exec-app" param="execute_extension limit:'hash ivr in',set:acc_code=cucu,playback:/var/sipxdata/mediaserver/data/ivrscript/CoralIVR/prompts/three.wav,system:/home/george/alex/test.sh,bridge:sofia/$${domain}/101@192.168.1.240,hangup inline"/>

 </condition>

 <condition field="destination_number" expression="3">

<entry action="menu-exec-app" param="execute_extension limit:'hash ivr in',set:acc_code=cucu,playback:/var/sipxdata/mediaserver/data/ivrscript/CoralIVR/prompts/five.wav,system:/home/george/alex/test.sh,bridge:sofia/$${domain}/101@192.168.1.240,hangup inline"/>

 </condition>

     </condition>
```

Comment: "now it is not working well" doesn't tell us anything. Please elaborate with more details, including any related error messages.

Comment: @DanVerdolino : Please now check the complete details and help me by giving proper solution

Answer (score 0):

Hi your script was incomplete with tags `</menu> </include>`.
I recommend you forever validate your XML script before you call it.